# I have a problem with a switch. It work one time but not two

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game to practice javascript. The goal of the game is as follows : several animal images are displayed on the screen. When the user clicks on the "play" button, a command of the type: "click on the duck" appears. Once the user has clicked on the duck, the image disappears and this instruction will no longer appear. The code I made almost works. My problem is the following: once the user has clicked on an image and clicked on "play" again, nothing happens. undefined script.js:39 appears in the console. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() { /*LES CONSIGNES SONT INVISIBLES*/
  $('#canard').hide();
  $('#cheval').hide();
  $('#cochon').hide();
  $('#coq').hide();
  $('#elephant').hide();
  $('#lion').hide();
  $('#mouton').hide();
  $('#paon').hide();
  $('#pinguin').hide();
  $('#singe').hide();
  $('#vache').hide();
  $('#zebre').hide(); /*DEFINITION DES VARIABLES*/
  var image_canard = $('#image_1');
  var image_cheval = $('#image_2');
  var image_cochon = $('#image_3');
  var image_coq = $('#image_4');
  var image_elephant = $('#image_5');
  var image_lion = $('#image_6');
  var image_mouton = $('#image_7');
  var image_paon = $('#image_8');
  var image_pinguin = $('#image_9');
  var image_singe = $('#image_10');
  var image_vache = $('#image_11');
  var image_zebre = $('#image_12');
  /*CREATION D'UN TABLEAU AVEC TOUTES
LES IMAGES*/
  var tableau = [image_canard, image_cheval, image_cochon, image_coq, image_elephant, image_lion, image_mouton, image_paon, image_pinguin, image_singe, image_vache, image_zebre]; /*FONCTION EXECUTEE AU MOMENT DU CLIC SUR "JOUER"*/
  $('#jouer').on('click',
    function() { /*PIOCHE ALEATOIRE DANS LE TABLEAU*/
      var random = tableau[Math.floor(Math.random() * tableau.length)];
      console.log(random); /*SWITCH EN FONCTION DE LA PIOCHE*/
      switch (random) {
        case image_canard:
          $('#canard').show();
          ($('#image_1').on('click',
            function() {
              $('#image_1').hide();
              $('#canard').hide();
              tableau.splice(image_canard);
            }));
          break;
        case image_cheval:
          $('#cheval').show();
          ($('#image_2').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_2').hide();
            $('#cheval').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_cheval);
          }));
          break;
        case image_cochon:
          $('#cochon').show();
          ($('#image_3').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_3').hide();
            $('#cochon').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_cochon);
          }));
          break;
        case image_coq:
          $('#coq').show();
          ($('#image_4').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_4').hide();
            $('#coq').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_coq);
          }));
          break;
        case image_elephant:
          $('#elephant').show();
          ($('#image_5').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_5').hide();
            $('#elephant').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_elephant);
          }));
          break;
        case image_lion:
          $('#lion').show();
          ($('#image_6').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_6').hide();
            $('#lion').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_lion);
          }));
          break;
        case image_mouton:
          $('#mouton').show();
          ($('#image_7').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_7').hide();
            $('#mouton').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_mouton);
          }));
          break;
        case image_paon:
          $('#paon').show();
          ($('#image_8').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_8').hide();
            $('#paon').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_paon);
          }));
          break;
        case image_pinguin:
          $('#pinguin').show();
          ($('#image_9').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_9').hide();
            $('#pinguin').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_pinguin);
          }));
          break;
        case image_singe:
          $('#singe').show();
          ($('#image_10').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_10').hide();
            $('#singe').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_singe);
          }));
          break;
        case image_vache:
          $('#vache').show();
          ($('#image_11').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_11').hide();
            $('#vache').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_vache);
          }));
          break;
        case image_zebre:
          $('#zebre').show();
          ($('#image_12').on('click', function() {
            $('#image_12').hide();
            $('#zebre').hide();
            tableau.splice(image_zebre);
          }));
          break;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code looks quite repetitive, why not create a function for the same?

Comment: also, it's not scalable, as you are using unique IDs, so for each ID, you will have to write a separate case.. instead, consider using data attributes and set the triggers accordingly

Comment: I start with JS that's wy my code is not very good... I'm just trying to make something work. I thought I would perfect it later.

Comment: You can not match jQuery objects.... There is a lot better way to do this without all that repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) incorrectly.

This function expects the first parameter to be a number which will be used as the start index from which elements will be deleted. You can pass a second parameter to specify how many items to be deleted (is all from the index to the end by default).

The parameter you're using (a jQuery object) is interpreted as `0` and that is why the `tableau` is emptied after the first function run.

To fix that, replace all calls to `.splice(...)` with:

```
tableau.splice(tableau.indexOf(random), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and I understood my mistake with your explanation. I'll try to make a less repetitive code but I'm happy that it works. Thank you